# What are the approaches to create and render a 3D image from 2D into browser

Tags: css, image, image-processing, 3d, textures

Let's say I have a simple image like below and I want to apply some colors/textures to it and enable the user view the result in 3D in a browser. I know applying the texture is a server-side task.
The problem is its extraction of 3D model and representation of it in the browser.

[image]

Questions are: what are the approaches to extract and present the 3D model in browsers?

Comment: Are you trying to somehow convert a flat image into a 3D model, or do you have the 3D model already?

Comment: @will The first thing I have to do is convert the above flat image into 3D. Then I need to show it in the browser!

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a way to just convert an image to 3D on the fly, otherwise 3D modelers would be out of a job! If you already had a 3D model you could present it on the web, but you can't dynamically generate one from an image. Even a 3D modeler would need multiple orthographic views to create an accurate model from this (a straight-on front, side, or top view)

Comment: @will Ok that makes sense. let's say I have a 3D model, how do I represent it on the web that users can view it?

Comment: What you'll need is called WebGL, and it is crazy overcomplicated - but there are libraries out there that make it relatively simple. Three.js is a good one, but is still a little tricky if you don't have much background in javascript https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene  There's also a libary developed by Mozilla called A-Frame that is super easy to use, but is for VR primarily - by configuring some stuff you could use it pretty easily for just model viewing, though! https://aframe.io/

Comment: Absolutely! I've been teaching myself how to use those libraries lately, there's so much you can do with them.